# how to implement one to one relationship if the relation has attributes?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have two tables in my database, `Department` and `Academic_staff`. the primary key in the `Department` table is `depId` and the primary key in the `Academic_staff` table is `aNo`.

Each department is managed by only one member of academic staff, so the relation between the two tables is one-to-one.

I need to record the date when someone of the academic staff starts managing a department, so the relation must have it's own attribute(`mStartDate`).

How can I implement this new attribute?

At first I was thinking to create a new table with three attributes (`depId`, `aNo`, `mStartDate`) and make two relations between the new table and the other two tables, but I then realized that it's not many-to-many relationship.

So how can I add the attribute `mStartDate` to the one-to-one relation between the two tables?

> There's more than one relation between the two tables, and some of those relations are one-to-many (the department employs more than one academic staff), so I can't merge the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed new table (which I shall refer to as DepartmentManagement) could in principle record the history of managers for each department, in which case it would be a many-to-many (temporal) relationship between Department and Academic.

However, if you want to record only the current manager, it's reasonable to "absorb" DepartmentManager into the Department table, giving two columns there (Manager_aNo and Manager_StartDate). Conceptually the object "DepartmentManagement" still exists, but it's absorbed, it doesn't have its own table.

You could also absorb it in the other direction (into Academic) but that wouldn't allow an Academic ever to manage more than one department. You might not need that now, but in principle it's more likely than having a Department with two managers.

Answer (score 0):

**Departments**

- depId
- fk_aNo (Unique )

*****- Primary key (depId, fk_aNo)*****

**academicStuffs**

- aNo (PK)

**newTable**

- depId  ---  ***Important "Both depId,aNo are from Departments, be sure"***
- aNo    ---
- mStartDate

  *- Primary key (depId, aNo)*

> Constraints--> a academicStuff can't start to manage a department more
>   than one time. If this structure proper for you and you want to enable
>   a aacademic stuff manage a department more than one time inform me.